# Why doesn't Azure Functions use other instances in app service plan to to process data?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function durable task that will spread into 12 smaller tasks. I am using dedicated plan, my maxConcurrentActivityFunctions is currently set to 4, and I have total of 3 instances (P3v2 - 4 cores) in the app service plan.

[image]

What I understand is, I should be able to process 12 concurrent tasks, and each instance should use all of its CPU to process the job, because the job is CPU oriented.

But in reality, scaling doesn't improve the performance, all of the task go to a single instance. Other 2 instances just stay idle, despite the fact that the main instance is being totally tortured and CPU usage always sit at 100% percent.

I am sure they go to the same instance because I can read that information from the log analytics. Every log has the same host instance id. If I filter out that host instance id, no logs will even get returned.

[image]

I also tested making 3 separated call, with 4 tasks in each. It also doesn't seem to use 3 instances too. The metric for the app service plan seem like, there can only be 1 instance online at a time, depite having 3 instances available. The dashline seems to mean "offline". Because when I filter by instance, it just show at 0.

[image]

Here is the host.json file

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "01:00:00",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "default": "Information"
    },
    "console": {
      "isEnabled": "false"
    },
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "ExcludedTypes": "Request",
        "isEnabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "durableTask": {
      "hubName": "blah",
      "maxConcurrentActivityFunctions": 4,
      "maxConcurrentOrchestratorFunctions": 20
    }
  }
}
```

My expection is. 12 tasks should immediately begin. And 3 instances should all be busy processing the data, instead of only 1 instance with 4 concurrent task.

Am I doing anything wrong. Or am I misunderstand something here?

Comment: could you please provide the `host.json` file how you configured?

Comment: Sure. But it hard to post code here, so I give you an image
https://i.imgur.com/UeIs5bJ.png

Comment: *hard to post code here* -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting . It isn't that hard!

Comment: Added to the question. I thought I was meant to post it through the comment (which is not possible to include codes). So I sent the image.

But now, I have added it to the question content.

Comment: What triggers the function? (e.g. to eliminate affinity)

Comment: The function is called by an Azure Function acitivity in Azure Data Factory. I guess it should be HTTP base. I also call it directly from my local machine using post man.

Answer (score 0):

1. As far as I know and as per the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans#how-does-my-app-run-and-scale)  Multiple applications in the same app service plan will share all the instances you have in your premium plan.
2. For example if you have if the app service plan is configured to run multiple VM instances, then all the apps in the plan will run on multiple instances.
3. In your case, the application you have is only one  but that application has many sub units (functions). So the application is using only one instance.
4. if you want to use all the instances then try deploying multiple function apps into the same app service plan.
5. Also, you can use Scaling functionalities or you can set by default [Auto Scaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/autoscale/autoscale-get-started) for the app service plan

Comment: "the application you have is only one..." hey do you mean there is a hidden config that restrict the number of instance an Azure Function app can use? It seems that the per app scaling feature is enabled in the app service plan, but I don't know if it is really the root cause or not.